# Preserved invariants by a flat family

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, deformation-theory

Let $X, C$ be schemes and $f: X \to C$ be a "flat family". That is $f$ is flat morphism. For sake of simplicity we can say that $f$ is surjective and $C$ is an irreducible curve that "parametrizes" fibers $f^{-1}(c) = X_c = X \times_C \operatorname{Spec} \ \kappa(c)$ of $X$.

The main meaning of "continuity" for flat morphism if that varying $c \in C$ preserves certain discrete invariats of the fibers like dimension, degree, arithmetic genus, etc. What I mean:

That for $s, c \in C$ the fibers $X_s$ and $X_c$ have same certain discrete invariants e.g. these which I enumarated above.

My question is if we can say more concretly **which** kind of invariants of the fibers are preserved by passing to the neighboured fibers.

All algebro geometric invariants? Only discrete ag invariants?  By an algebro geometric invariant I mean an object that one can associate to a scheme and it preserved under isomorphisms on category of schemes. That is if $X$ is a scheme and $A(X)$ is such algebro geometric invariant then by definition $A(X)=A(Y)$ if $X \cong Y$ as schemes.

My concern is that such "invariants" can be of really different nature. It can be a number like dimension of $\dim X$ or $n$-th cohomology group $H^n(X,O_X)$ but as well as an associated sheaf like the canonical sheaf $\omega_X$ (if $X$ nice enough). That is exactly the point.

Does there exist a criterion which characeracterize the algebro geometric invariants that can be associated to the fibers which are preserved in a flat family?

EDIT: As pointed out by Devlin the invariants I'm looking for are those which are determined by the Hilbert polynomial completly (say again for sake of simplicity $X$ assumed to be reduced). That is I can reformulate my question to: it there any criterion which allows to decide if a given algebro geometric invariant of a scheme is completly determined by the associated Hilbert polynomial?

Comment: I guess you are familiar with Hartshorne sections III.9--III.12 which contain important examples and non-examples. Certainly not "all" discrete invariants are constant in flat families: for example, a quartic surface in $\mathbf P^3$ containing a line has Picard number at least 2, but it deforms to a quartic with Picard number 1.

Comment: By the results of Hartshorne @Pop mentions, the invariants preserved in a flat family are essentially those determined by the Hilbert polynomial, and vice versa, at least over a reduced base. So perhaps the question could be productively framed as "which invariants can be read off of the Hilbert polynomial"?